# How to make a utility type that deep converts all fields that are not objects as optional? TS

Tags: typescript

original type:

```
type Foo = {
  zoo: number;
  bar: {
   a: number;
   b: string;
  };
  too: Array<string>;
}
```

I wanna get:

```
type PartitialFoo = {
 zoo?: number;
  bar: {
   a?: number;
   b?: string;
  };
  too?: Array<string>;
}
```

How to do it deeply? Help please

I just tried:

```
type PartialNotObject<T> = T extends object ? {
 [K in keyof T]?: T extends object ? PartialNotObject<T[K]> : T[K]
} : T
```

but this solution make every member is optional, i dont know how to do not optional for only (without arrrays) objects

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WkaaJN) what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: WOW, thank you! I spent a work day try to resolve this)

Comment: Please test against use cases before confirming; these deeply recursive types have all kinds of weird edge cases and I don't want to be halfway through writing up an answer and then find out that it doesn't actually meet your needs.  Test thoroughly and then let me know.  Thanks

Comment: I just tried with conditional types. That's work correctly https://t.ly/LTfGB THANKS!)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible approach:

```
type PartialNotObject<T> =
  T extends object ? T extends readonly any[] ? T : (
    { [K in keyof T]?: PartialNotObject<T[K]> } &
    { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends object ? 
        T[K] extends readonly any[] ? never : K : never]:
      PartialNotObject<T[K]> }
  ) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never : T
```

This is a recursive [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).  **CAVEAT**: such deeply recursive types often have bizarre edge cases that can be difficult to fix without refactoring the whole type.  All such types should be tested thoroughly against expected use cases before being put to use.

The basic idea is that if `T` is a non-array object then you should walk through its properties and ask the same question about each of its properties.  For each property that *isn't* a non-array object you should make it [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties).  For each one that *is* you should *not* make it optional.  And for these properties you need to recursively call `PartialNotObject` on them.

That's easy enough to say but the complication is that TypeScript doesn't have a simple way to map over a type and make just some properties optional.  So we need to break the type into the optional piece and the non-optional piece, and then [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) them together.  And *then*, to prevent ugly intersections from making things unreadable, we merge the intersections with [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).  The construction `⋯ extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never` will turn something like `{a: string} & {b?: number}` into `{a: string; b?: number}`.

Let's test it out:

```
type Foo = {
  zoo: number;
  bar: {
    a: number;
    b: string;
  };
  too: Array<string>;
}
type PartialFoo = PartialNotObject<Foo>;
/* type PartialFoo = {
    zoo?: number | undefined;
    bar: {
        a?: number | undefined;
        b?: string | undefined;
    };
    too?: string[] | undefined;
} */
```

That's what you wanted!  (Well, you didn't write `| undefined` but that is automatically added to the domain of optional properties.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAguE8AcFMAIAUCGAnUBLRAbAcge1APIBGAVtAMagA8AKgHywC8wssNs0AHqNAHYAmAZ1i5SFULAD8bDtz5DYyaIn65emcLES9wAbQC6UmQC5YAChatYAb1i6A0rDS9YAa2jhcAMzb7JppFQMHHxiMkpaB30GAF9YADJLVlsHJxd3Tx92RGEaKNkeAWFRcIlpPPtDLkKFJRU1DS0dAyNeaAA3aGRYU0dTNs7kfWMkq0D0LDxCMQiK6NgYywBKAvlhZy8u2AIjFMdnNw9vbeHt-Lj+jq3TGhBgCBhYADFcXCYbSwAvV-6AVwBbIhdADcliIKFM1lGiD+gJBoyIpkEoGQzgA5qDWDFMbBQD9YABBZDIRDgKjI1G8NF0UGLB5wcbBF5vRgIFATELTUpUZk04AAegAVLioAz2UzXu8oVZYN9cP5YLwAUDugAfWC-ATQLzOaD8HGscHISGjGWIBVKuFqjVanVtfWmqxEBUU9GwdWa-ja3UOmXY0Z4+VIlHoloe20+2mwQX8sCitlBLDMgCy2l+WClX1eFuV8MNEI+ZpzVoNsGdwcpGMs-tYgYVRJJZNdVL5i2AXvImBQcHaKFgnAC4qTr1BHa7Slgve6A4THJTaawwNg-P5IlcpLLFEQv0EcFAAAtoLutBOD3BBIh-tAgA)

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would share my solution which is admittedly very similar to @jcalz solution.

```
type PartialNotObjectOfObject<T extends object> = { 
  // handle array
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Array<unknown> ? K : never]?: T[K];
} & {
  // handle non-array objects
   [K in keyof T as T[K] extends object ? T[K] extends Array<unknown> ? never: K : never]: PartialNotObjectOfObject<T[K]>
} & {
  // handle non-objects
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends object ? never : K]?: T[K]
} extends infer O ? 
{ // prettify the intersection
  [K in keyof O]: O[K]
} : never;

type PartialNotObject<T> = T extends Array<unknown> ? T | undefined : T extends object ? PartialNotObjectOfObject<T> : T | undefined;
```

I think one of the key take aways here is how to prettify the intersection of objects as @jcalz has mentioned.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBMHsFMGdQHaQC6gA4CdrOQSwGYCeoA7gBbQKgCus04ouC+0GoAXABQBQyha0UAAUsOAoQA8AFQB8oALygA3t1CgA2gGlGVANbRCkfKCkBddia2nuAX269+goQEMMeZwBsAcigDyAIwAraABjZF98AOCw6VBoAA9kSnB4SCDQ5DlFJVBVUBBQMmcEcA9BVwxnQjy1LR1QfUNjKVBneCkrOMTk+ABBDErJagRdJBIEOQB+UG0LBGgAN1ZTSYsOzVMAbltQADJlPIKikrLESAQAWgqq0DTo5FgauqYGgyMTVvbOhKSS1PSwqBputTF1filQP1BhJhqNIOMpohFqwLLMkUsMOZhK53N4-ADwpECdIrDIdvsVGojsVSoIkJc7hlHrVtC9Gu8Wm1LBswT1bgSgejWBwZis1lYdj8+UwWGxfILuDkCphsOJQMgKOrHHlnno3sZfFjfBKbCL5hjtg4BNi3LhPD5wsTZAoPlK-pCBlUYSMxhNBS0AD40ErQfBMegilpuiGMwHTFy2+34+4RKIZaRyNagIPDcCh8PgTa5K2CABikEgLspoAAXhW5tQALb+VjbNT+VwWautBvN1s1fwWWDIDBMADmbdANknyHrHuhw9HCDHMm20-sfGtCdxDrTYXLlcU27teMd9wkB9XJZtO+TGSkcEJAGUR+OXcek2f0wAiJLD79kpuTg4ieu4Eg+w4RF4TYtmwR4gZ+e7IBIACMABMADMZLcCE5zDqA+Bzh+p5IQeVZ5B2GBdnYdhAA)